# Angular form validation , access form control while iterating over it on HTML

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I have a list of questions with answer options as radio button field. I'm getting these questions and answers from JSON file.so am iterating over it on HTML and assigning values to formControlName dynamically. My problem is how to validate while iterating over control values?

```
*ngIf="cricketForm.control.get('ques{{i}}').invalid" 

*ngIf="cricketForm.control.get('ques{{i}}').invalid"
```

this gives me an error. How to do it in the correct way?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yq4lyz-zt9b3h?file=app/form-field-overview-example.html
Right now validation is not working correctly

html file:

```
<form [formGroup]="cricketForm">
  <div *ngFor = "let user of userJson; let i =index ">
    <div class="label1" for="NameId">{{user.question}}</div>
    <mat-radio-group formControlName="ques{{i+1}}" aria-label="Select an option">
      <div *ngFor = "let option of user.options; let j =index">
        <mat-radio-button  [value]=j>{{option}}</mat-radio-button>
      </div>
    </mat-radio-group>


  <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="cricketForm.control.get('ques{{i}}').invalid" >This field is required</div>
  </div>
    <button (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
    <button (click)="onReset()">Reset</button>
</form>
```

ts file:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.cricketForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      ques1: [null, [Validators.required]],
      ques2: [null, [Validators.required]],
      ques3: [null, [Validators.required]],
      ques4: [null, [Validators.required]]
    })
    this.userDataService.getJSON().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.userJson = data;
      this.options = data.options
    });
}
```

Sample JSON Data:

```
[
{"question": "Who Was The First Indian To Hit A Test Century?", "options":["Lala Amarnath","Kapil Dev", "Sunil Gavaskar"],"ans":"Lala Amarnath"},
{"question":"Who Won The Inaugural Asia Cup Championship?","options":["Pakistan","Sri Lanka", "India"],"ans":"India"},
{"question":"Who Was Australia’s First Captain?","options":["F.S.Jackson"
,"D.W. Gregory", "Tony Lewis"],"ans":"D.W. Gregory"},
{"question":" When And Where Was The First Ranji Trophy Match Played?","options":["kolkata"
,"Mumbai", "Chennai"],"ans":"Chennai"}
]
```

Comment: Can you provide JSON data

Comment: Take a look at my library ngx-ez that does all the heavy lifting for form validation. https://github.com/adriandavidbrand/ngx-ez and a demo at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pytks5

Comment: @Sonam  Is there only four questions every time?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I'm doing for four questions.If questions no gets increased then I've to increase the form control in the ts file.Do you have better solution for this as well?

Comment: Create Dynamic Forms

Comment: It would be good if you provide a link of [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) having your code.

Comment: @Sonam I have tried this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yq4lyz Check and let me know

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I have forked ur project and created https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yq4lyz-zt9b3h?file=app/form-field-overview-example.html . I want validation for each field and if question is not answered that question should get red.

Comment: @Sonam So change the background color

Comment: @PrashantPimpale right now validation is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You has a syntax error. Must be

```
*ngIf="cricketForm.get('ques'+(i+1)).invalid"
```

See your [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-unr8or?file=app/radio-overview-example.html)

NOTE: I think you must try rethinking your code using FormArrays. The way is so simple as

```
<form formGroup="formArray">
  <div *ngFor = "let control of formArray.controls; let i =index ">
    <div class="label1" for="NameId">{{userJson[i].question}}</div>
    <mat-radio-group [formControl]="control" aria-label="Select an option">
      <div *ngFor = "let option of userJson[i].options; let j =index">
        <mat-radio-button  [value]=j>{{option}}</mat-radio-button>
      </div>
    </mat-radio-group>
  <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="control.invalid" >This field is required</div>
  </div>
    <button (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
    <button (click)="onReset()">Reset</button>

</form>
```

See that, we iterate over formArray.controls and use i=index. To show the labels use userJson[i]

where:

```
this.formArray=new FormArray(
    this.userJson.map(
      ()=>new FormControl(null,Validators.required))
);
```

Comment: Thanks Eliseo! I'll definitely apply your suggestion of using FormArray

Comment: 1 for form array!